# Cardano Wallet Server Invalid Argument

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, cardano-node

I'm trying to run cardano wallet server but it keeps me giving an error and have no idea what's wrong with it.
This is the command I run:

```
    cardano-wallet serve \
      --port 1919 \
      --node-socket /home/ubuntu/cardano-src/cardano-node/data/node.socket \
      --mainnet /home/ubuntu/cardano-src/cardano-node/mainnet-byron-genesis.json \
      --database /home/ubuntu/cardano-src/cardano-node/data \
```

This is the error:

```
Invalid argument `/home/ubuntu/cardano-src/cardano-node/mainnet-byron-genesis.json'
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved after deleting the path to the file. `--mainnet` doesn't need any parameter to pass.

```
cardano-wallet serve \
      --port 1919 \
      --node-socket /home/ubuntu/cardano-src/cardano-node/data/node.socket \
      --mainnet \
      --database /home/ubuntu/cardano-src/cardano-node/data \
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem you need a genesis file for the mainnet. Check here https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-wallet/user-guide/common-use-cases/how-to-start-wallet-server

Comment: I did download the file again from here: https://hydra.iohk.io/build/14528927/download/1/mainnet-byron-genesis.json but I still got the same error :/